# Changing the name of the site, list or permission group. Do I still all work

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have 4 sites, each site has its own permission-group
Each site has multiple lists on it, and each list has its own permission-group.
My question: is it possible to change the name of the sites, the lists and the permission group without losing its functionality. F.e: when I change the name of the site, is it then still connected to the permission group, another example: when i change the name of the list is it then still connected to the permission group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the site title or List title at anytime, it wont affect anything to the SharePoint Group.

SharePoint Site,List,Library,permissions are formed with GUID, so whatever you change, the GUID will not get change at back end. so no worries to change the title of list or tittle of site.

Adding one more point: Site title / list title will not impact the URL's also. only the file names will impact the URL .